# JSF Converter give null pointer exception

Tags: jsf, javabeans, converters

I had read all post related to my problem but I'm unable to find a solution. I created the converter to my Country entity, but when I submit the form the converter throw the ConverterException:

```
Cannot convert 105 to Country java.lang.NullPointerException 105
```

where 105 is the ID of the Country entity I selected in the form.

```
<h:outputText value="Country (*): " />
<h:selectOneMenu id="country" value="#{createUser.user.country}" required="true" requiredMessage="Please select a country." converter="#{countryConverter}" >
   <f:selectItem itemValue="#{null}" itemLabel="-- select one --" />
  <f:selectItems value="#{createUser.countries}" var="country" itemValue="#{country}" itemLabel="#{country.country}" />
 </h:selectOneMenu>
```

This is the converter:

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
@FacesConverter(forClass = Country.class)
public class CountryConverter implements Converter {

@EJB
private CountryDAO countryDAO;

@Override
public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) {
    if (!(value instanceof Country)) {
        return null;
    }

    return String.valueOf(((Country) value).getId());
}

@Override
public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String value) {
    if (value == null || value.isEmpty()) {
        return null;
    }
    try {
        return countryDAO.find(Long.valueOf(value));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new ConverterException(new FacesMessage(String.format("Cannot convert %s to Country %s %d", value, e.toString(), Long.valueOf((value)))), e);
    }
}
}
```

The CreateDao source:

```
@Stateless
@LocalBean
public class CountryDAO {

public CountryDAO() {
}
@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager em;
@Resource
SessionContext context;

public List<Country> getAllCountries() {
    TypedQuery<Country> query = em.createNamedQuery(Country.FIND_ALL, Country.class);
    return query.getResultList();
}

public Country find(Long id) {
    return em.find(Country.class, id);
}

public Country getById(long id) {
    TypedQuery<Country> query = em.createNamedQuery(Country.FIND_BY_ID, Country.class).setParameter("id", id);
    return query.getSingleResult();
}
}
```

If I use createDao.find(Long.valueOf(105)) within a Bean it works fine.
Where I wrong?

---

The problem seems to be related to the converter, because if I comment the try/catch clause

```
@Override
public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String value) {
    if (value == null || value.isEmpty()) {
        return null;
    }
    //try {
        return countryDAO.find(Long.valueOf(value));
//        } catch (Exception e) {
//            throw new ConverterException(new FacesMessage(String.format("Cannot convert %s to Country %s %d", value, e.toString(), Long.valueOf((value)))), e);
//        }
}
```

and modify the DAO to print something related to the country entity:

```
 public Country find(Long id) {
    Country c = em.find(Country.class, id);
    System.out.println(c.getCountry());
    return c;
 }
```

I see in the console:

```
FINE: SELECT ID, COUNTRY FROM COUNTRY WHERE (ID = ?)    bind => [1 parameter bound]
FINEST: Connection released to connection pool [read].
INFO: Italy
```

and in the browser:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at Converters.CountryConverter.getAsObject(CountryConverter.java:46)
at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicInputRenderer.getConvertedValue(HtmlBasicInputRenderer.java:171)
at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.MenuRenderer.convertSelectOneValue(MenuRenderer.java:202)
at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.MenuRenderer.getConvertedValue(MenuRenderer.java:319)
at javax.faces.component.UIInput.getConvertedValue(UIInput.java:1030)
at javax.faces.component.UIInput.validate(UIInput.java:960)
at javax.faces.component.UIInput.executeValidate(UIInput.java:1233)
at javax.faces.component.UIInput.processValidators(UIInput.java:698)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(UIComponentBase.java:1214)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(UIComponentBase.java:1214)
at javax.faces.component.UIForm.processValidators(UIForm.java:253)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(UIComponentBase.java:1214)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(UIComponentBase.java:1214)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(UIComponentBase.java:1214)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processValidators(UIViewRoot.java:1172)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.ProcessValidationsPhase.execute(ProcessValidationsPhase.java:76)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:593)
```

Comment: `createDao.find(Long.valueOf(105))` wont compile, you need a `String`

Comment: @AlexandreLavoie 105 is reaching as `String` currently (see the type of `value`).

Comment: @XtremeBiker I mean you are probably testing with `createDao.find(Long.valueOf("105"))` not `createDao.find(Long.valueOf(105))`

Comment: Yeah, got it, I've just seen the last line of the question ;-)

Comment: @Enrico where are you having the `NullPointerException`, is it in the `Converter` itself or into the `DAO` method? Just check the DAO is properly loading your country!

Comment: __Unrelated__: you don't need to annotate the converter class by `@FacesConverter(..)` while you've already defined it by `converter` tag attribute and performed interface implementation.

Comment: @XtremeBiker seeme to be related to the Converter, I re-edit the post the show you.

Comment: @Omar, `@FacesConverter` is not required as long as the converter keeps being a `@ManagedBean`. If not, it could be referred as `converter="countryConverter"` if it's a `@FacesConverter`. Anyway, @Enrico for the `NullPointerException` you will have to debug the Converter, however it doesn't seem to have any chance to throw a null pointer, does it?

Comment: @XtremeBiker yes you are ready. I'm very confused, because all seems to be working, I don't understand why the Converter throw a null pointer.

Comment: @XtremeBiker using the debugger and putting a breakpoint in the return line of the Converter i see: this type is `CountryConverter` and the value is `Converters.CountryConverter@d8381b`, the context is `FacesContextImpl` the component is `HtmlSelectOneMenu` and the value is a String with value "18". When I run over the breakpoint I receive the NullPointerException.

Comment: The only strange thing I see in the console is: `WARNING: Error while trying to load Bean ClassDAO.<error> : java.lang.ClassFormatError: Absent Code attribute in method that is not native or abstract in class file DAO/<error>` could be related to the problem.

Comment: Could be related to this setting? `<context-param><param-name>com.sun.faces.writeStateAtFormEnd</param-name><param-value>false</param-value></context-param>`